# Sitting on a toilet during Tisha B'Av

Tags: halacha, time, mourning-aveilus, tisha-bav, bathroom

May one sit on a toilet during Tisha B'Av, when sitting on chairs is generally forbidden? Are there any requirements that he hurry up as much as possible?

Comment: http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/coffeeroom/topic/sitting-on-toilet-and-bed-on-tisha-bav

Comment: What do aveilim in Shiva do?

Comment: I heard some people but something under there feet so that it will not be the "forbidden" height,  something like this http://www.tekspree.com/sharktank-squatty-potty-7-inch/?gclid=CJLHgM2N5sYCFZKRHwodkKMJwg

Comment: I'm not sure if I heard of a more ridiculous shailah in my whole life....I probably have but this might make the top 10.

Answer (score 9):

Rav Shumel Kamentzky, cited in sefer Kovetz Halachos pg 231, writes that a nursing woman or someone riding a bus may sit, because it is a necessary thing and not done out of enjoyment.

Sitting on the toilet is a need and not meant for enjoyment and should be the same.

Comment: Hey some people enjoy sitting on the toilet.

Comment: Some people prob are happy to sit on the bus even though ppl stand on the bus,halacha does not require it.